# How can I get my calculator to do more than one calculation? (C#)

Tags: c#, calculator

I created a calculator using Visual Studio and the C# programming language.
Everything works very well, except one thing.

I can't get the calculator to do more than one calculation at a time (for example: 3 + 3), I wish it could do 3 + 3 + 3 + 3, but I have no idea how to do it.

(I leave the piece of code that should interest you below)

```
    private void click_operazione(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double i;
        if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out i))
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            Operazione = b.Text;
            numero = double.Parse((textBox1.Text));
            hapremuto_operazione = true;
            textBox2.Text = numero + " " + Operazione;
        }
    }

    private void risultato_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hapremuto_uguale = true;
        switch (Operazione)
        {
            case "+":

                risultato = (numero + double.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + " " + textBox1.Text;
                textBox1.Text = risultato;
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + " = " + risultato;
                break;
            case "-":
                risultato = (numero - double.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + " " + textBox1.Text;
                textBox1.Text = risultato;
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + " = " + risultato;
                break;
            case "x":
                risultato = (numero * double.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
                if (risultato.Length <= 15)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + " " + textBox1.Text;
                    textBox1.Text = risultato;
                    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + " = " + risultato;
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "errore";
                    textBox2.Text = "errore";
                }
                break;
            case ":":
                risultato = (numero / double.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + " " + textBox1.Text;
                textBox1.Text = risultato;
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + " = " + risultato;
                break;
            case "%":
                risultato = ((numero * double.Parse(textBox1.Text)) / 100).ToString();
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + " " + textBox1.Text;
                textBox1.Text = risultato;
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + " = " + risultato;
                break;
        }
        ha_appena_messo_una_virgola = false;
    }
```

I haven't tried anything yet, no ideas come to my mind

[image: calculator]

Comment: Hint, you need to store the previous result.

Comment: Do you type one number <enter>, operator <enter> next number <enter> ?
If you enter the entire string at once "3+3+3+3" I would miss functions like string.Find, string.IndexOf, string.Substring, etc.

Comment: I don't think there is any string parsing happening here.

Comment: Can you post an image of your form so we can know how your design looks.

Comment: I'm not going to make sure that after the user clicks "equal" he can continue to make calculations with the result, this thing can already be done .. what I had in mind was to do like the Iphone calculator (not knowing if they also make the other calculators), that is, every two numbers automatically does the result
(if I do 2 + 2 + 2, the calculator will do 2 + 2 = 4 + 2)

Comment: @AstrikezYT Do you need to support parentheses, or just keep doing simple binary expressions using the previous result?

Comment: @EdPlunkett My problem is that I don't know how to do it ... I'm still at the beginning ..

Comment: @AstrikezYT After calculating a result, stick the result in the left-hand textbox and set the right-hand textbox to empty text. Focus the right-hand textbox. Then let them choose another operator, type another right-hand operand, and click "equals" again. I'm making some assumptions here because you still haven't shown us your UI, as preciousbetine asked.

Comment: @EdPlunkett https://imgur.com/u6YL4rT

Comment: @EdPlunkett done

Comment: @AstrikezYT I think at the end of `resultato_Click` you just need to set `numero = resultato;`? Next time around `numero + double.Parse(textBox1.Text)` will get you the previous result, plus whatever' snow in textBox1.Text.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: @AstrikezYT When you say "does not work", you're asking me to *guess* what happened. It's like you're playing a game with me. But I don't want to play a game. What you need to do is fix whatever went wrong. I can't help you do that because I have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I don't know how to explain it, nothing happens ...
it's exactly like before.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I can't understand what should change this way, every time I click + anyway the "numero" variable is set to the value of the textBox1 .. in what way this should help to do more operations consecutively without needing to click the "equal" button

Comment: @AstrikezYT So add another variable. You need to keep track of the result of the previous operation. That becomes the left hand operand of the next operation.

Comment: @EdPlunkett this already happens, if when I click the "equals" I click + it works correctly.
I'm interested in having it automatically do the operations, like if the user automatically writes 2 + 2 WITHOUT clicking the "equal" button, it comes out 4, so that if it repeats + it can do this infinitely .. .
it is just a matter of comfort, to avoid having to click "equal"

Comment: @AstrikezYT What if the user wants 2 + 20?

Comment: In current state question is way too broad for SO as it seem to ask for design approaches and suggestion for features. @AstrikezYT you may want to spend some time to clarify for yourself what exactly you want to achieve first and then [edit] the question. I.e. based on the attempted answers people even can't figure out if you want expression input (like `(2+3)/4^2 + 22` or  calculator-style input, based on your last comment you may even want "guess my result as I type" sort of feature...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `delegate` that accepts a method reference for you calculation

See [Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/).

```
public delegate double CalculateExpression(double value1, double value2);
```

You then then need to create methods that have the same parameter list as the delegate and same return type.

For example this will multiply:

Overall, I would suggest looking into delegates to solve this problem.

```
public double Multiply(double value1, double value2)
{
    return value1 * value2; 
    // add validation and etc. if needed instead of returning 
    // immediately .
}
```

Creating and using this delegate in the calling method.

```
var calcExpression = new CalculateExpression(Multiply);
double result = calcExpression(10, 10); // result is 100.
```